# - Clojure - I get an error when I run this fibonacci function, any idea what's wrong?

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, clojure

I picked up clojure a few hours ago and am trying to get a Fibonacci function working

Here is the function I'm defining

```
(defn fib [x]
  (if (or (= x 1) (= x 2))
    ((inc 0))
      ((+ (fib (- x 1)) (fib (- x 2))))

))
```

and I get this error: `java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  user/fib (NO_SOURCE_FILE:3)`

Though I'm unfamiliar with almost all the language constructs this seems to be correct as far as I know. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've made the classic mistake of too many parens, in Lisps, parens mean "apply this function" so it's important to only put them around functions:

```
(defn fib [x]
  (if (or (= x 1) (= x 2))
      1
      (+ (fib (- x 1))
         (fib (- x 2)))))
```

Your error essentially means "Hey, you just tried to apply a number!" so we need to remove the redundant parens.

Comment: Thanks! I thought the if form went like (if (condition) (iftrue) (iffalse) )

Comment: @Jeroko Nope, almost no forms in lisp involve wrapping subexpressions in parans :) PS if I've ansewred your question, check the checkmark to mark it as closed